# Disable all email notifications

Tags: 2013, email

I am working on a migration from 2010 to 2013 and have setup a development farm. I need a way to disable all outgoing emails or have all emails go to me. I have searched but can not find anything on disable emails. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Wouldn't change the outgoing email-server to something else work, or am I reading your post to literally?

Comment: That worked perfectly, I just had to remove the mail server from the list of servers within the farm. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know, one method which i used in my test farm.
Basically i remove the all settings from the Outgoing email setttings from Web App.

For Single Web App:

- Central Administration > Application Management > Manage Web
  Applications.
- On this page click on the web application name  then from ribbon
  Select the Outgoing email settings( if click drop down of General
  settings).
- Now remove the Outbounf SMTP server name and other settings.

this will disable outgoing emails for the web application.

For the complete farm, you can remove the same setting

- Central admin > System Settings > Configure outgoing e-mail settings.
- On this page remove all the values.

Comment: As a side note this does not work if the mail server is listed under servers. This is what I tried but had to remove my mail server first.

Answer (score 1):

I had a scenario where I had to turn of mail for certain web applications but I did not want to disable outgoing mail totaly. It is a testfarm.

I used this script to set SMTP server for each Web Application with url that contains sp2010. Where "turnedOff" is a false smtpadress to make sure the webapplications does not use the default SMTP set for the farm.

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication | where {$_.url -like "*sp2010*"}
foreach($wp in $wa){
$wp | Set-SPWebApplication -SMTPServer turnedOff
$wp.update()
}
```

or for simply 1 web application:

```
Set-SPWebApplication -Identity "http://someURL" -SMTPServer TurnedOff
```